# How do use indentation with new paragraphs, with the Strict Adherence to SIGS style template (ACM)?

Tags: acm

I am using the Strict Adherence to SIGS style template, which can be found here: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates

Each paragraph starts on a new line. However, I would like each new paragraph to use indentation, so that I can save some space.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is "Option 2: LaTeX2e - Tighter Alternate style - (may reduce the total number of pages)" on the linked page.